# If $f: B \rightarrow C$ and $g: A \rightarrow B$ be two functions let $h = f \circ g$. Then for $h$ to be onto what can we say about $f$ and $g$?

Tags: functions

Let $f: B \rightarrow C$ and $g: A \rightarrow B$ be two functions and let $h = f \circ g$. Given that $h$ is an onto 
function, which one of the following is TRUE?

(a)  $f$ and $g$ should both be onto functions

(b)  $f$ should be onto but $g$ need not to be onto

(c)  $g$ should be onto but $f$ need not be onto

(d)  both $f$ and $g$ need to be onto

I found that both $f$ and $g$ both should be onto but in the answer it is given that $f$ should be onto but $g$ need not to be onto. But I found a case in which option (b) will be wrong, i.e; $A = \{a,b,c\}$, $B = \{1,2,3\}$, $C = \{x,y,z\}$, and $g(a)=2$, $g(b)=3$, $g(c)=2$, and $f(1)=x$, $f(2)=z$, $f(3)=y$.

Here $g$ is not onto and $f$ is onto but $f \circ g$ is also not onto.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y\in C$ then since $h$ is onto there's $x\in A$ such that $h(x)=f(g(x))=y$ so we have $z=g(x)\in B$ and $f(z)=y$. We proved that $f$ is onto.

Comment: yes f definitely has to be onto but we can't say with surety that g need not be onto as it fails in the example I gave above in the question.So, according to me for h = fog to be onto both f & g need to be onto.Correct me if I'm wrong !!!

Answer (score 0):

The questions asks, Given that h is an onto function, which one of the following is TRUE?
You're trying to explain in which cases premise fails.
Think , given premise which cases are valid.

Given that h is an onto :
1) if $g:A→B$ is not onto : $|B|\geq |C|$
Yes , $|B| < |C|$ is possibility as well , but that invalidates premise.
So , above explains why $g$ need not be onto.
2) if $f:A→B$ is not onto : I guess , it's self explanatory why this would invalidate premise.

Answer (score 0):

In your "counter example" you do not have that $h$ is onto. So your condition on $h$ is not met, so we cannot consider one of the 4 answers.

And as Sami Ben Romdhane already showed, we have $f$ is onto. To see that $g$ does not need to be onto, consider the following example:

$A = C = \{ 1 \}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$. If we define $f(2)=f(3)=1$ we have that $f$ is onto and we define $g(1)=2$, so $g$ is not onto. However, we have $h(1) = f(g(1))=f(2)=1$ so $h:A \to A$ is onto.